# customze picklist diplay value

Tags: angular, primeng, picklist

I need to customize pickly display value.
For example the list to left can be 3 field and the list to right must have 6 field. I read the [doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/picklist) , but they don't show anything.

The used this code:

```
<p-pickList [source]="list1" [target]="list2">
    <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <img src="assets/showcase/images/demo/car/{{car.brand}}.png" style="display:inline-block;margin:2px 0 2px 2px" width="48">
            <div style="font-size:14px;float:right;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{car.brand}} - {{car.year}} - {{car.color}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

They modify only the columns about the left list ( 2 field), is there a way to modify the columns abut the right way? I mean the left columns must have 3 and the right columns must be 6 field. Anyone can hep me?